# Python treats + as a digit?

Tags: python, string, digit

Basically im making a small piece of code to remove the end character of a string until the string passes `.isdigit`.

```
def string_conversion(string):
    for i in string:
        if i.isdigit == False:
            string = string[0:len[string]-1]
            print(string) #This is just here to see if it goes through
test = "60+" 
string_conversion(test)
```

I used http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to see why I wasn't getting any output, it passed a + symbol as a digit, just like the numbers 6 and 0.

Am I doing something wrong or does python treat `+` as a digit?

Comment: `if i.isdigit() == False:` or simply `if not i.isdigit()`. You need to call your method.

Comment: You are forgetting parenthesis: `i.isdigit()`.

Comment: `string = string[0:len(string)-1]` can be simplified as `string = string[:-1]`

Comment: You could have diagnosed this yourself by `print`ing `i.isdigit`

Comment: length of string can be calculated by `len(string)` not `len[string]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) is a method not an attribute, so (as was already mentioned in the comments) you need to call it.

Also you check each character (starting from the left side) for `isdigit` but if it's not passing the `isdigit()` test you remove a character from the right side. That doesn't seem right. You probably wanted to iterate over the `for i in reversed(string)` (or using slicing: `for i in string[::-1]`).

But you also could simplify the logic by using a `while` loop:

```
def string_conversion(string):
    while string and not string.isdigit():
        string = string[:-1]
    return string
```

Comment: No, i was trying to remove a character from the right side in this instance, but thanks for the help, this helps alot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_conversion(string):
    for i, s in enumerate(string):
        if s.isdigit() == False:
            string = string[:i]
            break
    print(string) #This is just here to see if it goes through

test = "60+"
string_conversion(test)
```

Try This